# For what values of $\lambda$ is the distribution $(x-i\varepsilon)^\lambda$ positive?

Tags: mathematical-physics, conformal-field-theory, dirac-delta-distributions

I've been reading the famous unpublished paper by Luescher and Mack "The energy momentum tensor of critical quantum field theories in 1+1 dimensions". In the proof of their main theorem, page 7 of the manuscript, they write:

"$$
<0|O_k^\dagger(x) O_k(y)|0> = B_k (x-y-i\varepsilon)^{2k-6}, \quad B_k\in\mathbb{C},\; x
\in\mathbb{R}
$$

This distribution should be **positive**. As is well known [5], this implies $2k-6\le 0$. Thus $O_k = 0$ for $k>3$."

[5] is Gelfand, Shilov "Generalized functions, Vol I".
Here $k=0,1,2,\dots$

I found in this book that for $\lambda = -n$, where $n$ is a positive integer,

$$
(x-i0)^{-n}=x^{-n} + \frac{i\pi(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\delta^{(n-1)}(x),
$$

where the distribution $x^{-n}$ for $n=2m$, i.e. $n$ even, is defined

$$
(x^{-2m},\phi)=\int_0^\infty x^{-2m}\left(\phi(x)+\phi(-x)-2\left[\phi(0)+\frac{x^2}{2!}\phi''(0)+\dots+\frac{x^{2m-2}}{(2m-2)!}\phi^{(2m-2)}(0)\right]\right)dx
$$

I tried calculating the inner product with $\phi(x)=\exp(-x^2)\ge 0$ for various $\lambda$'s. However, for $\lambda = -2$ I got
$$
((x-i0)^{-2},\phi)=(x^{-2},\phi)=\\
\int_0^\infty \frac{\phi(x)+\phi(-x)-2\phi(0)}{x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty \frac{2\exp(-x^2)-2}{x^2}dx=-2\sqrt\pi<0
$$
so that according to Lieb and Loss "Analysis" definition of a positive distribution, $(x-i0)^{-2}$ is **not** positive, whereas according to the paper the distribution *should be positive* at least for $\lambda=-6, -4, -2,0$.

**Definition of positive distribution** (Lieb and Loss)
A distribution $T\in \mathcal{D}'(\Omega)$ is positive if $T(\phi) \ge 0\; \forall \phi \ge 0$, where $\phi\in \mathcal{D}(\Omega)$. Here $\phi \ge 0$ means that $\phi(x) \ge 0 \;\, \forall x\in\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$.

The paper can be found here, the operators $O_k$ are defined on page 6:
[Luescher and Mack "The energy momentum tensor of critical quantum field theories in 1+1 dimensions"](http://luscher.web.cern.ch/luscher/notes/cft2d.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you mean $x$ one or two dimensional variable. I don't have the article at hand but I guess we probably mean $D=1$??

The argument goes as follows: you have to use Bochner's theorem, which says that $W(x-y):=W_2(x,y)$ is positive distribution if and only if the Fourier transformation yields is a positive measure
$\tilde W(p) d^Dp$.

In this case the Fourier transformation is something like
$$
\tilde W (p) \sim \frac{\theta(p_0)\theta(p^2)}{(p^2)^{\frac D2 +\lambda}}
$$
see e.g. Remark 2.2. in Ref. 1.

Then you get for $\lambda \geq 0$ this is not integrable. Also $d=0$
is a trivial special case.

Reference:

1. N. M. Nikolov & I. T. Todorov, "Rationality of Conformally Invariant Local Correlation Functions on Compactified Minkowski Space", [*Commun. Math. Phys.* **218** (2001) 417-436](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002200100414), [arXiv:hep-th/0009004](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0009004).

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it later today. [The article](http://luscher.web.cern.ch/luscher/notes/cft2d.pdf)

Comment: I think your answer is right and I have seen something similar elsewhere. Now I am interested where my calculation went wrong so I posted a [follow-up question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1398721/contradiction-to-bochners-theorem-for-distributions).